# How to set different hyperlinks to database array results?

Tags: php, html

[image]

I have an array of usernames from a database. Using a for each loop, I can print each of these usernames with other details such as paragraphs created by each user and the date of paragraph creation.

I can set a single hyperlink to all of the usernames # but I want to set a hyperlink to each usernames so that when you click on different usernames, you can go to different pages. How do I do that with the most simplest solution possible?

I'm a novice/beginner.

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. It would be **beneficial for you** to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Please read through that and you'll see how Stack Overflow works, *"learning the ropes"* as it were. It will give you a good idea on how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help you have a better and positive experience here, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
function create_ulink(&$item1, $key)
{
    $item1 = "<a href = '/customlink.php?uname=$item1'> $item1</a>";
} 

array_walk($usernames, 'create_ulink');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Took me a while to figure and understand array_walk but it worked as solution on what I was trying to do.